# Postgresql cannot be reached

Tags: centos, postgresql

We are trying to access (server1)postgresql port 5432 on a different server(server 2) but we are not able to reach it.

Checking done:

- port 5432 running/listening postgresql.conf
- listening address okay:listen_addresses = '*'
- pg_hba.conf also good: host    all             all             0.0.0.0/0               md5
- firewall is also okay since packet trace results shows that server1 has been reached but denied by the
  server/application/db
- Firewalld is off and allowed tcp on port 5432 in iptables.

Any other suggestions or possible cause why can't we establish the connection?

Comment: What is the error that you received?

Comment: The telnet only shows us that it's only trying to connect. But we had a tcpdump running on server1(postgresql server) and there was a hit but the connection is not establishing.

Comment: If the connection isn't establishing there's something wrong at the network or firewall level.  Also try to `telnet localhost 5432` from server1 to make sure postgresql is working without the network in the middle.

Comment: Yup, I did that earlier, connection to itself is working properly. I've been thinking of the network too but its able to reach my server when traced via tcpdump.

Comment: @chicks comment is on target, but also try `telnet (server1 IP) 5432` *from server1* to ensure it is listening on the public IP.  If that is good, then turn the firewalld/iptables/whatever off temporarily, or set it to pass **everything**.  Then test again.  If it works, then the problem is your firewalld/iptables/whatever.

Comment: Everything went well after we restarted the postgresql, seems that the new configurations on postgresql.conf didn't take effect when they first edited the config to allow our IP's.